# Can't load or find the main class in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, classloading

So I was doing a JDBC connectivity program I made a new project on eclipse and created a class then I installed the connectivity driver and uploaded the path into the modulepath then after writing the code and running it, it shows the error like "Could not find or load main class JDBCExample in module MyProject"

I tried to upload the path of the jar file into classpath from the modulepath but still the output error remain the same..

Comment: You've messed up your run target; it has nothing to do with the dependencies: The system can't find the code you just wrote. Go into the run menu, delete the run target, right click on your class that contains your main method and select 'run'.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points that you can surely check before running:

1. Check if the project's build path is configured and the required libraries are present.
2. Check the Installed JRE in the eclipse preferences
3. Create/Edit a Run configuration and check if the classpath is set correctly